# Find point in certain array values and replace with comma

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => 308.5
            [2] => 2009

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Price
            [1] => 308.5
            [2] => 2009

        )

)
```

and i need to replace `"."` with `","` `in key [0][1], [1][1], [2][1]` etc

Comment: Is this for localized display or something? If so, I would suggest keeping you data as a float and simply using something like  `NumberFormatter` to change the format for display. That way you can continue to operate with the value as float without having to change back and forth between float and string swapping out periods for commas.

Comment: That's nice to know. You're aware that a Q&A site works best when there's an actual question, right?

Comment: my goal is  print array to table. Before adding array to table i need to sort array by second key value where price is, but it seems that usort cant sort numbers with point. I get all my data from csv that is generated by another script in server

Comment: @Omerimuni `usort` will sort based on whatever function you provide it to sort on. You just need to make sure your comparison is treating this like a float probably. IN this case you should be able to do a very simply comparison like `return a > b;` and the comparison will work for float. If this is numeric data, you need to make sure and treat it as such.

Comment: @MikeBrant
return a > b; was the key. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

This will work, **notice how you have to use `sub_array` with a reference**

```
foreach ($arr as &$sub_arr) {
  foreach ($sub_arr as &$val) {
    $val = str_replace('.', ',', $val);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use a reference in the second loop too.

Comment: @georg Where exactly ?

Comment: `foreach($sub_arr as &$val)`

Comment: @georg Oh right you mean without using a `$tmp` value. Of course, I just wanted to emphasize the more tricky reference needed on the first loop. (Edited anyway, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach($arr as $v) {
  foreach($v as $v1) {
    $newarr[] = str_replace('.', ',', $v1);
  }
}
print_r($newarr);
```